# Bookdown: What's the purpose of plugin-highlight.css

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm using Bookdown with the Gitbook template. I've noticed that this template contains a `plugin-highlight.css` stylesheet with rules for highlight.js. However, highlight.js is not enabled in the template and the default highlighting seems to user other scripts/styles.

I've now disabled the default highlighting and added highlight.js myself. When I do this, the template picks up the styles in `plugin-highlight.css` and these override the highlight.js stylesheet I've added myself.

So I'm wondering: What's the purpose of `plugin-highlight.css` in this template? Is it just a leftover? Or am I supposed to use this template when I use highlight.js, so it matches the Gitbook styles?